# C# Modbus get a lot register every 20 seconds

Tags: c#, modbus, modbus-tcp

I've made an application with C#, in this application I have to read every 20 second 840 registers of PLC via Modbus TCP. I use this library http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/16260/Modbus-TCP-class. When I use the method

`Master.ReadHoldingRegister(ushort id, byte unit, ushort startAddress, ushort numInputs)`

It return a bytes array of lenght 144 and not 1680, do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a packet size limit in ModbusTCP. You'd just have to read it in chunks increasing the startAddress each time

Comment: I've tried to use this method, I did 10 times this function and in Modbus simulator is everything ok but in phisical PLC, it "sees" the first 2 calls of function

Comment: i've used a different lib and encountered a similar problem, my solution was to add a little delay between the calls

Comment: Can you say me that library have you used? Thanks

Comment: @JamesBarrass Indeed, Modbus [TCP response] payload size should be limited to 256 bytes, but the library itself may already be transparently splitting the thing into subsequent requests (that's not for sure). However, as VeNoMiS says, the requests could be arriving to fast for the PLC processing time, and be discarded. A delay should be added either programmatically or possibly as a setting in the library context.

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I have inserted 500 millis of delay and now it's everything ok

Comment: I suggest @VeNoMiS to post his advice in the form of an answer so he may get the rep he/she deserves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested add a bit of delay between the calls.

Answer (score 2):

Modbus allows up to 125 holding registers to be read in a single Read Holding Registers function call. If the library does not throw an error on a call to 840 registers, then it is probably taking this limit into account by spliting your call in several Read Holding Registers requests. I would study the source code to be sure that you can do that reliably.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. Upvoted for the '122' limit... could you link some reference for that number?

Comment: The limit is actually 125. You can find it in the Modbus Application Protocol Specification: [link](http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b.pdf ). I will update my answer to state the correct limit.

Comment: The limit by standard may be 125, but not every device even has that. I worked with a VFD that, as per the documentation, could only read 37 holding registers in a single packet. Check documentation or firmware.